# scipy.interpolate.interp2d Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I don't know the functional form of my data. Can I still use scipy.interpolate.interp2d??? I basically have 3 arrays. Two corresponding to the co-ordinates and the 3rd is the data points.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I have two array [x] and [y] which are basically co-ordinates and corresponding data value in another array [D] where D=f(x,y). But I don't know the functional form. I only have discrete values. Now I want to get D at all (x,y). I was wondering if interp2d can do the job @Bonifacio2